# Converting code c# sync httprequest to async

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, asynchronous

I have a problem with this codes, i need to convert this Json httprequest to an async method, in order to use it in a WP7 C# application, here is the code, i really need help on this one.

it shows errors in the following statements:

1) myReq.ContentLength = postData.Length;--> ContentLength is not contains this type of method

2) webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse(); --> is a Sync method and is not contained on httpresponse metod

3) StreamWriter stOut = new StreamWriter(myReq.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII); --> is a Sync method and is not contained on httpresponse metod

4) GoogleCell cell = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Response);--> method overloaded or missing a conversion....and the conversion is on the 3rd error.

```
  /// internal google cell info to post

    public GoogleCell GetCellInfo(string lac, string mnc, string mcc, string cellID)
    {

        HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/loc/json");
        myReq.Method = "POST";
        myReq.ContentType = "application/jsonrequest";
        string postData = "{\"cell_towers\": [{\"location_area_code\": \"" + lac + "\", \"mobile_network_code\": \"" + mnc + "\", \"cell_id\": \"" + cellID + "\", \"mobile_country_code\": \"" + mcc + "\"}], \"version\": \"1.1.0\", \"request_address\": \"true\"}";
        myReq.ContentLength = postData.Length;

        StreamWriter stOut = new StreamWriter(myReq.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
        stOut.Write(postData);
        stOut.Close();

        HttpWebResponse webresponse;
        webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();
        Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);

        string Response = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
        loResponseStream.Close();
        webresponse.Close();

        GoogleCell cell = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Response);
        return cell;


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

converted the complete class in an WCF still have errors on

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Response);